# Android Button Tag and Onclick listener in listview get reset when scrolling

Tags: android, android-listview, android-mediaplayer, listactivity, simplecursoradapter

I am populating a listview with an imageButton that when clicked, starts playing an audio file.

I set the datasource of the MediaPlayer from the

```
ImageButton.setTag("resource url")
```

while populating the list. 
Without scrolling, the first record is playing fine, but once I scroll, all of the ImageButton tags, 
and `onClickListener` are lost.

To enable the click for the buttons on the list, I implement my own `customOnClick` and set it in the XML part.

```
//the list row button xml: 
<ImageButton
android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
android:layout_width="30dp"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:background="@drawable/play_icon"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:tag="file_recording"
android:onClick="myOnClick" />


the customCursorAdapter:

class customCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
        private int layout;
        Context context;


        public customCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor cursor,
                String[] from, int[] to) {
            super(context, layout, cursor, from, to);
            this.layout = layout;
            this.context = context;

        }
@Override
        public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
            ViewHolder holder;
            int flag = 1;
            if (view != null) {
holder.player = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);

                view.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
            }

//I get the URL of the audio file:

String recording= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("recording"));

//set the ImageButton tag to the url:
holder.player.setTag(recording);    

}

@Override
        public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            final View view = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);

            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int id) {
            return id;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }
```

Please help me.

Comment: mind to post the codes on how you set your onClickListener?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `OnClickListener` in the Adapter `getView()` function.

Comment: I am not using button.setOnClickListener, I am using a method that is called on the click using the xml property android:onClick="myOnClick", I think that's the way to do it when you have buttons on the listview.